# Rhythmbox & Virt-Manager won't launch on 22.10 - errors seems to be related to "controls.cpp"

Tags: kubuntu, rhythmbox, qemu, virt-manager, 22.10

### Edit 2

Virt-Manager was reporting the same last 2 lines whenever it locks up.

```
[Sat, 29 Oct 2022 17:13:55 virt-manager 72529] DEBUG (vmwindow:185) Showing VM details: <vmmDomain name=Lubuntu id=0x7f6495534a00>
[Sat, 29 Oct 2022 17:13:55 virt-manager 72529] DEBUG (engine:316) window counter incremented to 2
[Sat, 29 Oct 2022 17:14:04 virt-manager 72529] DEBUG (vmmenu:210) Starting vm 'Lubuntu'
[Sat, 29 Oct 2022 17:14:04 virt-manager 72529] DEBUG (connection:706) node device lifecycle event: nodedev=net_vnet5_fe_54_00_9b_81_f9 state=VIR_NODE_DEVICE_EVENT_CREATED reason=0
[Sat, 29 Oct 2022 17:14:04 virt-manager 72529] DEBUG (connection:646) domain agent lifecycle event: domain=Lubuntu state=VIR_CONNECT_DOMAIN_EVENT_AGENT_LIFECYCLE_STATE_DISCONNECTED reason=1
[Sat, 29 Oct 2022 17:14:04 virt-manager 72529] DEBUG (console:721) Starting connect process for proto=spice trans= connhost=127.0.0.1 connuser= connport= gaddr=127.0.0.1 gport=None gtlsport=None gsocket=None
[Sat, 29 Oct 2022 17:14:05 virt-manager 72529] DEBUG (connection:631) domain lifecycle event: domain=Lubuntu state=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_RESUMED reason=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_RESUMED_UNPAUSED
[Sat, 29 Oct 2022 17:14:05 virt-manager 72529] DEBUG (connection:631) domain lifecycle event: domain=Lubuntu state=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_STARTED reason=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_STARTED_BOOTED
[10:02:07.081617086] [72643] ERROR Controls controls.cpp:689 Control 0x00000000 not in the idmap
[10:02:07.081631226] [72643] FATAL default controls.cpp:654 assertion "validate()" failed in ControlInfoMap()
Killed
```

---

### Edit 1

I purged and reinstalled some `gstreamer` packages (some failed).  After reinstall, I now only get the last 2 lines.

---

I'm seeing this when I launch Rhythmbox from the terminal:

```
$ rhythmbox

(gst-plugin-scanner:40127): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 23:47:20.545: type name '-a-png-encoder-pred' contains invalid characters

(gst-plugin-scanner:40127): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:47:20.545: g_type_set_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:40127): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:47:20.545: g_type_set_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:40127): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 23:47:20.585: type name '-a-png-encoder-pred' contains invalid characters

(gst-plugin-scanner:40127): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:47:20.585: g_type_set_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:40127): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:47:20.585: g_type_set_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed
[4:56:17.344798916] [40127] ERROR Controls controls.cpp:689 Control 0x00000000 not in the idmap
[4:56:17.344816885] [40127] FATAL default controls.cpp:654 assertion "validate()" failed in ControlInfoMap()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was that package, or cpp-11, in 22.10 repo that was causing my issue as I'm now able to start it after removing `cpp-11` & `g++-11` packages, along with reinstalling `cpp-12` & `g++-12` packages.

I reported it in my [Launchpad bug 1993751](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-11/+bug/1993751) & [1993760](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/1993760).